# How do I get this simple sales tax calculator to not break and clear fields?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

All I'm trying to do is get this not to break when I press calculate, and have the clear button clear the two text fields.  I know I have a simple error and it's a quick fix, thanks for the help!

http://jsfiddle.net/Be9P6/

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
Sub total: <input id="subtot" value="5" type="text"/><br/>
Tax %: <input id="tax" value="6" type="text" /><br/>
<input id="calc" type="submit" value="Calculate" />
<input id="reset" type="submit" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#calc').click(function(){
        var taxf = ($('#tax').val() / 100);
        var tot = ($('#subtot').val() * (taxf + 1)).toFixed(2);
         alert("Your total is $" + tot);
         $('#form').submit();
    });
    addTax()
})
```

Comment: You're submitting the form, reloading the page ?

Comment: I wasn't trying to reload the page.  I'm new to jQuery so I might have accidentally done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change some stuff. Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Be9P6/1/).

**What I've changed:**

1. Your reset button needs to be of the type [reset](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms13.htm).
2. Taken out the hard-coded values as setting these as default will
   make them un-eligible to be reset.
3. Added semi-colons to your function call and final closing brackets
   for good practice.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form">
Sub total: <input id="subtot" value="" type="text"/><br/>
Tax %: <input id="tax" value="" type="text" /><br/>
<input id="calc" type="submit" value="Calculate" />
<input id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#calc').click(function(){
        var taxf = ($('#tax').val() / 100);
        var tot = ($('#subtot').val() * (taxf + 1)).toFixed(2);
         alert("Your total is $" + tot);
         $('#form').submit();
    });
    addTax();
});
```